# How to determine top 2 records in an array object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array where I need to get top two records, based on the `count` property in JavaScript:

```
[
   {name: "tom", count : 2},
   {name: "sam", count : 4},
   {name: "dan", count: 1  }
]
```

Here the output should be :

> [tom, sam]

Comment: Is that supposed to be an array?

Comment: yes it;s an array containing object.. i want o sort just based on count and get top 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort based on the `count` property and use `.slice` to get the top two.

```js
const arr = [
   {name: "tom", count : 2},
   {name: "sam", count : 4},
   {name: "dan", count: 1  }
];
const res = arr.sort((a,b)=>a.count-b.count).slice(-2).map(({name})=>name);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [
   {name: "tom", count : 2},
   {name: "sam", count : 4},
   {name: "dan", count: 1  }
];

function compare(a, b) {

return b.count-a.count;
  
/*
 
  if (a.count > b.count) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.count < b.count) {
    return  1;
  }
  return 0; */
}

console.log(arr.sort(compare).slice(0,2));
```

Comment: this is good, although not sure why the extra step of creating countA & countB variables. also no need to create comparison variable either.